# How to create SQLite database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created a Databasehelper.java class and in that class I have called SQLite database class and implemented all its methods and in the main class when I am calling this class instance and  when I am running the app It is showing "Unfortunately your app has stopped"

this is code

```
package com.example.android.viewpager1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 5/1/2016.
 */
public class Databasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Answers.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="answers_table";
    public static final String COL_1="QUESTION_NO";
    public static final String COL_2="QUESTION_ANS";



    public Databasehelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
    db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME+"(QUESTION_NO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,QUESTION_ANS VARCHAR);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME);
      onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

and this is mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.android.viewpager1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    Databasehelper mydb;

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
        initialisePaging();
        mydb=new Databasehelper(this);//here I am making DB 

    }
```

here I am making database but it is not running and  I also know that on the main thread or UI thread we should not create database or networking object and fro that we should use AsynTask class  but can anyone tell how to use it or any other solution 
 the logcat are

05-02 01:34:29.710 32328-32328/com.example.android.viewpager1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.viewpager1/com.example.android.viewpager1.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEanswers_table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEanswers_table (QUESTION_NO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,QUESTION_ANS VARCHAR);
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2141)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1221)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:574)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEanswers_table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEanswers_table (QUESTION_NO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,QUESTION_ANS VARCHAR);
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.viewpager1.Databasehelper.onCreate(Databasehelper.java:27)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.viewpager1.Databasehelper.(Databasehelper.java:22)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.viewpager1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5056)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1221) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:574) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Why create a DB in your app? Deploy the pre-created DB it with your app.

Comment: I have to use SQLite DB only

Comment: I have used Sqlite DB only which is provided by android only

Comment: You can create a SQLite DB and deploy it with your app by putting it in the ASSETS folder of your android project

Comment: @VikasKumar try reading the logcat it points out valuable information for debug

Comment: you have not given space between exist and table name in onupgrade method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax problems in your code that I will point out but fixing them doesn't guarantee your app works, you still need to read Logcat for further information:

1- `db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME+" ("+ COL_1 +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+COL_2+" VARCHAR);");`

(note the added spaces after "table" and before "(" and also using your columns constants instead of hard coded strings)

2- `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);`

(note for the added spaces after EXISTS)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give space between 'TABLE_NAME' and '('. See the updated code. Let me know in case of any query.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
    db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME+" ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,QUESTION_NO INTEGER  AUTOINCREMENT,QUESTION_ANS VARCHAR);");
    }
```

Comment: that does not solved the problem still it is not running